# To nil out outlets in a custom UIView's dealloc under ARC?

Tags: ios, uiview, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

Usually in a UIViewController subclass, I nil out all outlets in viewDidUnload. But in my custom UIView, should I nil out those outlets (defined in my custom UIView) in dealloc instead? Does ARC perform these actions automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, still do it in viewDidUnload to get them out of memory as fast as possible.

ARC means you don't *need* to do it anywhere but it's still a bit more efficient if you do.

Though you don't ever need to nil properties in deadlock when using arc in any of your classes.

Comment: How about outlets defined in a UIView subclass? Do I have to nil out those outlets in UIView subclass's dealloc? (Of course, the UIView subclass is nil out in UIViewController's viewDidUnload)

Comment: no - you don't need to dealloc any properties in dealloc in any class when you are using ARC. NB That doesn't mean you can just remove all your deallocs without thinking; you still might have to do other things like remove notification listeners etc :)